# Jupyter Notebook hangs while crawling an API

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a python code which crawls a particular API and gets the data in a dataframe. The notebook hangs at a random point while showing the kernel as busy. I've tried Pycharm, Anaconda 3, and Anaconda 2.

For instance, if I am crawling 2000 items, the code sometimes stops after 10th item, sometime after 45th item or so on. It's completely random. 
Also, this code runs completely fine at my colleague's systems.

What can I do to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Are you clicking into the console window accidentally by any chance? Do you get any error messages? Does your code start running again or will it stop forever? Does it proceed after pressing ENTER?

Comment: Nope. I am not clicking on console window, neither any error message. It stops forever and I have to start again where it fails again :(

Just checked my CPU & Ram usage. My CPU usage is almost 95-98% due to other processes. Can that be the reason to it?